# Any tools/libraries to convert ppt and pdf files to flash swf on server side?

Tags: flash, pdf, powerpoint

I'm building a pet project which needs to convert pdf and ppt files to flash swf files on the server side. This should look similar to what Scribd, Docstoc or Slideshare these websites do. But after some googling, I couldn't find any open source tools or libraries to do this except the OpenOffice wrapper. So I'm wondering how those websites do it or maybe there are some tools/libraries I don't know?

Thanks,

Wei

Comment: just an update. Thanks for the replies. I settled down with FlashTools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your ppts into pdfs. And then use [swftools](http://swftools.org/) for converting pdf (using openoffice, you can use uno bridge, which is available in C, C++, python, java, for automating the whole pdf conversion)) into swf. Its an open source library and it is damn good.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could convert from PPT to JPEG and then replay the slideshow, but that would be without the animations and special effects... take a look at http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the [scribd API](http://www.scribd.com/developers/api?method_name=docs.upload) to upload your file, and embed the scribd file in your site?

Comment: because this project is meant for some internal use for our lab. We don't want to upload our documents to a public server cause there might be copyright issues with some of the documents. Also we would like more control over the viewer, which all these websites doesn't provide.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something similar a while ago. It's not pretty - I used open office to convert the ppt files to pdf, then used imagemagick to convert the pdf files to images, then wrote a flash player to display the images.