# Use OpenOffice to do server-side ppt(x) to swf conversion

Tags: flash, powerpoint, openoffice.org

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use OpenOffice in server mode as a multithreaded service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625241/how-can-i-use-openoffice-in-server-mode-as-a-multithreaded-service)

I'd like to turn Powerpoint presentations to SWF files the same way that OpenOffice does it, except automatically through a command line call. I came across [Any tools/libraries to convert ppt and pdf files to flash swf on server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886144), which led me to explore PyUNO bridge, which comes with OpenOffice as well as the OpenOffice command line API, but I wasn't able to make anything productive of it. Any guidance is appreciated. If there is a good solution outside of OpenOffice, I would be happy to try it too.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625241/how-can-i-use-openoffice-in-server-mode-as-a-multithreaded-service